# How to install modules to Luajit using Luarocks

Tags: lua, luajit, luarocks, luasocket

I managed to install luasocket and works fine using lua5.3 but i can't find the way to install them to require from luajit.

If i write print(_VERSION) it shows luajit use lua5.1.

This is the stuff i been trying:

```
luarocks install luasocket

luarocks --local install luasocket

luarocks --lua-version 5.1 install luasocket

luarocks --lua-version 5.1 --local install luasocket

luarocks config lua_version 5.1

luarocks install luasocket

sock = require("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.1/socket")

package.path = package.path .. ";/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.1" require "socket"

package.path = package.path .. ";/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1" require "socket"

...
```

The error:

```
$ luajit
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall. http://luajit.org/
JIT: ON ARMv7 VFPv3 fold cse dce fwd dse narrow loop abc sink fuse
> sock = require("socket")
stdin:1: module 'socket' not found:
        no field package.preload['socket']
        no file './socket.lua'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/socket.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
        no file './socket.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0xaba4406d
```

I tryied to move the installed files to some of those paths but still don't work.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
luarocks --lua-version 5.1 install luasocket
```

is the proper way to install it.

That should also tell you in the last line of output where it installed the module, so you can check if that's in your `package.path`.

---

It seems you just misunderstand how `package.path` works. From the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath):

> A path is a string containing a sequence of templates separated by semicolons. For each template, the function replaces each interrogation mark (if any) in the template with a copy of name wherein all occurrences of sep (a dot, by default) were replaced by rep (the system's directory separator, by default), and then tries to open the resulting file name.

What that means is that a path like `/usr/share/lua/5.1` won't find anything, because it doesn't find a valid Lua file at that path and since there's no `?`, no substitution is done whatsoever. The first of the two paths is OK, but many Lua modules use a file called `init.lua` instead, so for every `<path>/?.lua` you should always also add a `<path>/?/init.lua` to cover that option as well.

*Normally* Luarocks should install the packages main Lua file at `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua`, but for your case that doesn't seem to work. You can have a look at that directory and see if the file is there at all, and check that `luarocks config deploy_lua_dir` actually returns `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1`.

Comment: I add the path before require and get: ...com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua:12: module 'socket.core' not found:
        no field package.preload['socket.core']
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/socket/core.lua'

Comment: Try `luarocks list --lua-version 5.1 socket`, that will tell you what rock tree it's installed in

Comment: I tryied everything. Same happens to modules in current folder. I can't find a way to make require not useless. io.read works fine. Now i been trying to include a file in a subfolder of a proyect and again stucked.  I even tryied to use os.execute("pwd > currentpath"), read this file and add the path to package.path. Just keep saying can't find the module.

Comment: lua5.3: server.lua:36: module '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/downloads/SERVER/services/lua/config/static_headers.config' not found.    This is the full path and the file obviously exists. I can cat the file using this path.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed something about your code. Updating my answer now @StringManolo

Answer (score 1):

socket.lua was installed to a directory that doesn't exist in your LUA_PATH

find where socket.lua was installed, with find or mlocate, if installed:

```
find / -name socket.lua 2>&1 | grep -v Perm

sudo updatedb  &&  locate socket.lua
```

`~/.luaver/luarocks/3.2.0_5.1/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua`
`~/.luaver/luarocks/3.2.0_5.3/share/lua/5.3/socket.lua`
`/usr/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua`
`/usr/share/lua/5.2/socket.lua`
`/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket.lua`

edit your .bashrc  --  assuming a bash shell here, but others follow a similar process.  take your pick, and modify accordingly  https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Shells

find the line that says `export LUA_PATH='/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;yadda-yadda`

add a semicolon plus the path(s) you found from above.

```
export LUA_PATH='/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1'
```

close any open terminals, then open a fresh one, now that you have that new path enabled.

---

alternatively, you can use softlinks.

```
ln -s /usr/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua
```

I'm not a fan of this secondary softlink method, because you'd have to do it for every Lua module that resides outside of your path, but I'm including it so you know your options.  If it's just for that particular module, this would be an acceptable solution, because it does what you set out to do.  However, in the future when you run into the same issue with other modules, you would have to repeat the process for those, as well.  Modifying the LUA_PATH is your best bet.

Comment: find / -name socket.lua 2>&1 | grep -v Perm

sudo updatedb  &&  locate socket.lua
this commands do not return anything. Anyway i know where is installed. I tryied to copy in all the paths luajit is searching for and not working.

Comment: Don't copy in all the paths Lua is already searching through - that's redundant.  Just add in the path where socket.lua resides.  You probably decimated its install by attempting to move that module to another directory.  `luarocks remove luasocket`, and any other instances of socket.lua, which you'll need to learn how to use `find` or `locate` to discover, then reinstall luasocket.

Comment: With `LUA_PATH` you can use a double semicolon `;;` and Lua will just insert the default path there.

Comment: That's not the problem.  StringManolo already stated in the original question that `stdin:1: module 'socket' not found:` and then a list of all the default locations that it's searching through.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing, you stated:

> "I add the path and get: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/**socket.lua**
> module 'socket.core' not found..."

That's because socket.lua exists in that directory, but you moved it's subdirectory:

> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/**socket/core.lua**

So that dir will no longer do anything for you until you *delete it and begin again.*

```
rm /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua
rm -rf /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/socket/

luarocks --lua-version 5.1 install luasocket
```

Now watch carefully as it installs, to see what directory it actually installs to,
or use that `find` command I mentioned earlier to locate your Lua5.1 compatable socket location **and add that to your LUA_PATH**.

```
sudo apt install mlocate  &&  sudo updatedb  &&  locate socket.lua
```

You don't need to add these directories to your LUA_PATH as they're already being searched

```
> sock = require("socket")
stdin:1: module 'socket' not found:
        no field package.preload['socket']
        no file './socket.lua'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/socket.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
        no file './socket.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
        no file '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

`;;` won't do anything because you've already pointed out that it doesn't reside in any of those default dirs.

It is possible that it's looking for the right dir, but the wrong extension.

> /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.**so**
> as opposed to /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.**lua**

in this case, use the softlink method I mentioned earlier, making sure to use the correct location, this is just an example:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.lua /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so
```

Comment: I think is a core.lua bug in luasocket 5.1 version.